# How do I detect a pan gesture that starts outside my view?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on its `UIView`, inside a `UINavigationController`. I need to detect vertical pans, even if they start in the navigation controller's navigation bar. At the moment, my handler method only gets called if the pan starts inside my controller's view.

How do I detect a pan gesture that starts outside my view?

Comment: Did you try adding the same gesture recognizer to the other view?

Comment: The other view belongs to the UINavigationController, not to my controller.

Comment: The fact that the other view belongs to UINavigationController shouldn't be that big a deal: after all, you are planning to steal gestures from that view :)